# Why mutable default parameter behaves this way?

Tags: python, parameters, default, keyword-argument

I'm aware of mutable parameter behavior. Why the list is not set up to None when I send and unpack **dictionary as argument? The common_header.png repeads, it means is stored in list. That is weird to me and I couldn't find answer for the question...
I'm learning, happy to hear any other suggestions to code, thank you

```
def print_user_profile(gender='female', first='Jane', last='Doe=', pictures = None):
    if pictures is None: pictures = []
    gender_options = ('male', 'female')
    
    if gender not in gender_options: return 'Gender not correct'
    elif gender == 'male' and first == 'Jane': first = 'John'

    pictures.insert(0, 'common_header.png')

    print(f'The user {first} {last} has the following pictures:')
    for i in pictures: print(i)
```

```
test_data1 = {
    "gender": "male",
    "last": "Brown",
    "pictures": ["holidays1.png", "easter_grandma.png"]
}

print_user_profile(gender='male', last='Brown', pictures=["holidays1.png", "easter_grandma.png"]) 
print_user_profile(gender='male', last='Brown', pictures=["holidays1.png", "easter_grandma.png"]) 
print_user_profile(gender='male', last='Brown', pictures=["holidays1.png", "easter_grandma.png"]) 

print_user_profile(**test_data1) 
print_user_profile(**test_data1) 
print_user_profile(**test_data1)
```

```
The user John Brown has the following pictures:  
common_header.png
holidays1.png
easter_grandma.png

The user John Brown has the following pictures:
common_header.png
holidays1.png
easter_grandma.png

The user John Brown has the following pictures:
common_header.png
holidays1.png
easter_grandma.png

The user John Brown has the following pictures:
common_header.png
holidays1.png
easter_grandma.png

The user John Brown has the following pictures:
common_header.png
common_header.png
holidays1.png
easter_grandma.png

The user John Brown has the following pictures:
common_header.png
common_header.png
common_header.png
holidays1.png
easter_grandma.png
```

There is no problem if I send the same arguments separately.

Comment: Why would it be none?. You explicitly set it to the same *list*.

Comment: Not really, there are 2 different listst id depends how I send arguments to the function, but the functions react differently and gives different output although arguments are the same.

Comment: you give it the same list in all 3 of the second set ... you could cause the same behaviour in the first set ... by putting the list in a variable and giving the same variable to all 3 of the first ones...

Comment: @Paul-Mazu If you include the cases without using `kwargs` as well, then there are *four* different lists. The one in the dict and three in the calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your bug is of course straight forward, but I can see it can be challenging in the start. you repeatedly give the "pictures" element of "test_data_1", and that one is then mutated within your function.

If you want to avoid that, make a copy of the list inside the function, e.g. via

```
pictures = [] if pictures is None else list(pictures)
```

Comment: I see it now, OMG, so silly, thank you again

Answer (score 2):

In your code, when you pass the list explicitly to each call, you create a new instance of the list.

When you pass as a dictionary, you are calling with a single instance of that list three times.

We could change your code to use the same list six times, and you'll see the same behavior with both calling conventions.

```
pictures = ["holidays1.png", "easter_grandma.png"]

test_data1 = {
    "gender": "male",
    "last": "Brown",
    "pictures": pictures
}

print_user_profile(gender='male', last='Brown', pictures=pictures) 
print_user_profile(gender='male', last='Brown', pictures=pictures) 
print_user_profile(gender='male', last='Brown', pictures=pictures) 
print_user_profile(**test_data1) 
print_user_profile(**test_data1) 
print_user_profile(**test_data1)
```

Which outputs:

```
The user John Brown has the following pictures:
common_header.png
holidays1.png
easter_grandma.png
The user John Brown has the following pictures:
common_header.png
common_header.png
holidays1.png
easter_grandma.png
The user John Brown has the following pictures:
common_header.png
common_header.png
common_header.png
holidays1.png
easter_grandma.png
The user John Brown has the following pictures:
common_header.png
common_header.png
common_header.png
common_header.png
holidays1.png
easter_grandma.png
The user John Brown has the following pictures:
common_header.png
common_header.png
common_header.png
common_header.png
common_header.png
holidays1.png
easter_grandma.png
The user John Brown has the following pictures:
common_header.png
common_header.png
common_header.png
common_header.png
common_header.png
common_header.png
holidays1.png
easter_grandma.png
```

Comment: Thank you, could you elaborate a bit? test_data is dictionary, after unpacking with ** shlould send the same arguments

Comment: @Paul-Mazu: Elaborated. When using the explicit arguments you have three unique instances of the list object.

Comment: OMG! I see it now... oh goshhh